Linking form for relative homology
There is a linking form $Tor(H_l(X,\mathbb{Z}))×Tor(H_{n−l−1}(X,\mathbb{Z}))→\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Is there some generalization like $Tor(H_l(X, A; \mathbb{Z}))×Tor(H_{n−l−1}(X,A; \mathbb{Z}))→\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for relative homogy? It looks very natural, but I can't find any reference.
